# Why slip is negative in this plot?

Tags: motor, dc, generator, induction-motor, torque

I have the following plot (please see first 2 plots below).

The asynchronous motor is working as a generator. I wonder why the slip is going negative, is it because the torque also goes negative? Like what would be the mechanism behind the behaviour? My take is that the slip is becoming negative as the torque is negative as well.

[image]

[image]

The following machine has been used to achieve equilibria:

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: Your take is exactly right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positive slip is defined as how much rotor lags behind the rotating magnetic field when it is rotoring, due to the load torque resisting the torque applied by the rotor.

And if zero slip is defined as when there is no-load and the rotor is aligned with the rotating magnetic field, then it only stands to reason that negative slip is how much the rotor leads the rotating magnetic field when it is generating, due to the load torque being applied to the rotor in a way that assists the machine rather than resisting it.